# Matlab: Obtaining sequential curve-fitting variables names in a loop and outputing the fitting results into a .txt file

Tags: matlab, for-loop, output, sequence, curve-fitting

In a loop, the variables `struct.Angle0225` and  `struct.Intensity0225` within the function`fit(struct.Angle0225 ,struct.Intensity0225, 'gauss4')` are needed to sequentially change their name. The Matlab code bellow is obviously wrong and is attached for clarification:

```
for number = 225:230
s = sprintf('%04d', number);
fit(struct.Angle(s) ,struct.Intensity(s), 'gauss4')

end
```

The above-mentioned loop is required to yield the following:

```
fit(struct.Angle0225 ,struct.Intensity0225, 'gauss4')
fit(struct.Angle0226 ,struct.Intensity0226, 'gauss4')
fit(struct.Angle0227 ,struct.Intensity0227, 'gauss4')
fit(struct.Angle0228 ,struct.Intensity0228, 'gauss4')
fit(struct.Angle0229 ,struct.Intensity0229, 'gauss4')
fit(struct.Angle0230 ,struct.Intensity0230, 'gauss4')
```

Each `fit` will give the following **results** in the command window:

```
ans = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)
```

Matlab is required to output a report of the **results** above for all the `fit` sequences in a .txt file, preferably in the following format:

```
225 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)



226 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)

227 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)



 228 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)

229 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)

230 = 

     General model Gauss4:
     ans(x) = 
              a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2) + 
              a3*exp(-((x-b3)/c3)^2) + a4*exp(-((x-b4)/c4)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =   1.917e+04  (1.877e+04, 1.957e+04)
       b1 =       113.3  (113.1, 113.5)
       c1 =       10.42  (10.13, 10.72)
       a2 =        7652  (7312, 7991)
       b2 =       146.2  (145.6, 146.9)
       c2 =       18.59  (17.43, 19.75)
       a3 =        9165  (8841, 9490)
       b3 =       321.5  (320.8, 322.2)
       c3 =       37.53  (36.04, 39.03)
       a4 =        5409  (5195, 5623)
       b4 =       124.1  (119.7, 128.6)
       c4 =       185.2  (168, 202.5)
```

Or a table like the following:

```
File    a1  b1  c1  a2  b2  c2  a3  b3  c3  a4  b4  c4
0225                                                
0226                                                
0227                                                
0228                                                
0229                                                
0230
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using a matrix for this?

Comment: I do not exactly know how to use a matrix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i=225:230
struct.(['Angle0' num2str(i)]) = struct.(['Intensity0' num2str(i)]) = [];
fit(struct.(['Angle0' num2str(i)]), struct.(['Intensity0' num2str(i)]), 'gauss4')
end
```

try this code for generating dynamic struct fields

Comment: This works perfectly for the fist part, and it renamed the files sequentially. I tweaked it a little: 'for i = 225:230
s = sprintf('%04d', i);
fit(struct.(['Angle' num2str(s)]), struct.(['Intensity' num2str(s)]), 'gauss4')
end'

Comment: Do you have an idea how to output the reports into a table or a .txt file?

Comment: you can use this resource: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html